# HIDE/SHOW Subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, subview

I have a subview that loads via

```
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    [self.view addSubview: self.webView ];
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 911, 768, 52);
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

For starters how would i make it so i can hide it once its up and then show it again via double clicking the bottom of the app. and also how would i make it animated so it slides up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to animate the view that it slides up and down, you have to animate its properties, or what I would suggest you is to use presentModalViewController animated:YES

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html